# JQuery: Reload page when Countdown reaches Zero

Tags: jquery, refresh, countdown, countdowntimer, page-refresh

I am trying to finish a CountDown clock with JQuery. Evrything is working fine except the last part, where I pretend to make the page to reload when the countdown reaches 0. This is what I have got:

1- First I crete the container:

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
iDiv.id = 'countdown'; 
iDiv.className = 'countdown';
```

2- Now the clock

```
// Countdown Clock JQuery
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
// JQuery function
jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5, 
        display = $('#countdown');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    if (fiveMinutes === 0) {
          location.reload();
        }
});
```

Well, everything works fine but this last bit:

```
if (fiveMinutes === 0) {
    location.reload();
    }
```

The page wont reload on countdown reaching zero. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can reload it by setTimeout:

```
// JQuery function
jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5, 
        display = $('#countdown');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    setTimeout(function(){ location.reload() }, fiveMinutes*1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a far more elegant way to do it than the solution I reached. I added another var listening for the counter to reach 0 (00:00), and despite it works, it was just an ugly patch.

 var expired =
window.setInterval(function(){
  if($("*:contains('00:00')").length > 0){
    document.location.reload(true);
  }
}, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

The If condition is executed only once, during the first executing of the script. At that point fiveMinutes variable is 60*5 (300) and does not match the === 0 condition.

```
// JQuery function
jQuery(function ($) {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5, 
        display = $('#countdown');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
    if (fiveMinutes === 0) {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

You need to check that the timer runs to 0 in the;

```
setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = duration;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Function so the condition check is executed within the timer value updates.

Hopefully this helps.